# extjs 3.3.1 change panel tbar in runtime

Tags: javascript, extjs, toolbar

I'm having 2 **Ext.Toolbar**. tbar1 and tbar2.

I want to switch between them in runtime according to some event - so that when the event is called tbar1 is docked to the panel and in the next time tbar2 is docked to the panel instead of tbar 1.

Is there a way to do it?

Could not find possible solution in the extjs 3.3.1 documentation:
http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/docs/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following "method" (Works on ExtJS 4.x)** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/xmkm2Lpq/)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var myPanel = Ext.create(Ext.panel.Panel, {
    height: 300,
    width: 500,
    title: "Panel Header",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        margin: '10 0 0 10',
        text: 'Show Toolbar X',
        listeners: {
            click: function (me, options) {
                var panel = me.getBubbleParent();
                var xToolbar = panel.dockedItems.items[1].items.items[0];
                var yToolbar = panel.dockedItems.items[1].items.items[1];
                xToolbar.setVisible(true);
                yToolbar.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        margin: '10 0 0 10',
        text: 'Show Toolbar Y',
        listeners: {
            click: function (me, options) {
                var panel = me.getBubbleParent();
                var xToolbar = panel.dockedItems.items[1].items.items[0];
                var yToolbar = panel.dockedItems.items[1].items.items[1];
                xToolbar.setVisible(false);
                yToolbar.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }],
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        itemId: 'container1',
        hidden: false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Add'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Edit'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Delete'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Update'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        itemId: 'container2',
        hidden: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'New'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Open'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Save'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Undo'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            text: 'Redo'
        }]
    }]
})});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, ExtJs 4 has alot easier way to do it - just by using addDockedItem and RemoveDockedItem.  That's why Im asking about ExtJs 3 and not 4. Could not find a way to do it in 3.